# How do I associate a minor mode to a particular file or a set of files based on extension?

Tags: emacs, clojure

Currently, every time I open a text file in emacs, I have to `M-x longlines-mode` in order to get my line-wrapping turned on. Likewise in clojure, I have to `M-x paredit-mode` (although it does automatically set the major modes to text and clojure, respectively).

I am hazy on the difference between major and minor modes, but I'm thinking the above-mentioned modes are minor. Is there a way to:

1. configure emacs to open all clojure (*.clj) files with `paredit-mode` automatically?
2. configure a particular file (say, notes.txt) to open with `longlines-mode`. I have tried adding `-^- mode: longlines -^-` or `-^- mode: longlines-mode -^-` as suggested in other threads, but it doesn't seem to work. I can't search for documentation on the `-^-` syntax because I don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have this in my .emacs file

```
(require 'clojure-mode)
(defun turn-on-paredit () (paredit-mode 1))
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'turn-on-paredit)
```

Comment: perfect! It works. And using a similar pattern for longlines-mode successfully initiated longlines mode whenever text-mode is turned on. I'm guessing there is a bit of luck that 'text-mode-hook is defined. Thx again

Comment: It's not luck; almost every mode (every one I've ever seen, in fact) will have `$(mode-name)-hook` defined. You can add as many functions to that as you want.  Another way to do the above is just: `(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (lambda () (paredit-mode 1)))`

Comment: The standard macros for defining major and minor modes automatically cause a `MODENAME-hook` to run. (It *is* possible to define modes without using those macros, though, so it's not an absolute guarantee; but the majority of modes do use them.)

Comment: For me it worked by removing the first line. What is it for? Sorry for such a newbie question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative code with the same effect could be (also untested, but should work):

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.clj$\\'" . paredit-mode))
```

Comment: This answer is only relevant to major modes.

Answer (score 0):

See the section on file associations in [this tutorial](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/emacs/emacs-4.html).

Basically, what you want to do is this (untested, but should work):

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.clj$" . paredit-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

You can repeat the same procedure for text files and long-lines-mode.

Comment: I added this, and it successfully opened a .clj file in paredit-mode, but it was no longer associated with clojure-mode

Comment: @jk that's odd. It should treat it as a minor mode.

Comment: Nope, when you associate a file using auto-mode-alist, it considers it a major mode. You need to use hooks to enable minor modes.

Comment: This works for me for certain types of files and modes: (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\CHANGES\\'" . makefile-mode)).

Answer (score 0):

You can put mode name just in the first nonblank line, preceded and followed by ‘-*-’. Other text may appear on the line as well. For example,

```
; -*-longlines-*-
```

or

```
; -*- mode: longlines -*-
```

You can see detail in:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html